# Maths in JDatabaseQuery

Tags: php, sql, joomla

Which syntax I should use in JDatabaseQuery for this query

```
SELECT
  username,
  num_contacts + num_interests * 10 + num_dates * 100 + num_closenesses * 1000 AS Practice
FROM aasgz_users
ORDER BY Practice DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT
  username,
  num_contacts + num_interests * 10 + num_dates * 100 + num_closenesses * 1000 AS Practice
FROM aasgz_users
ORDER BY Practice DESC;

use following,

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo():
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('username,(num_contacts + (num_interests * 10) + (num_dates * 100 ) + (num_closenesses * 1000)) AS Practice')
 ->from('#__users')->order('Practice DESC');
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Now you will get result